# Django 2 models 1 "queryset"

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a news model and a media model.

I'd like to show all the objects on the news page ordered by date.
They both have date fields and are ordered by ["-date"].

is there a way to do this in the template or should I create a new list and sort the objects in the view?

Thanks in advance.

Ignacio
I've read that a few times over the years.
How does it relate to my question?
[ Ignacio deleted his comment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used something like this:

```
objects = list(queryset1)+list(queryset2)
objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)
```

Now for the models I have defined a new method:

```
def gettype(self):
        return self._meta.verbose_name
```

which basically gives you the name of the model.
Now, in the template you can differentiate between the objects like this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if object.gettype == "mediaitem" %}
        {{ object.some_attribute }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```